# "MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set" Zekr Qur'an study software java error

Tags: java

I installed Zekr Qur'an study software on Ubuntu 12.04 and I upgraded to 12.10. Then the Zekr app started giving me this error whenever I start it.

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initMozilla(Mozilla.java:1939)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Mozilla.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:99)
    at net.sf.zekr.ui.QuranForm.makeFrame(QuranForm.java:628)
    at net.sf.zekr.ui.QuranForm.init(QuranForm.java:340)
    at net.sf.zekr.ui.QuranForm.<init>(QuranForm.java:319)
    at net.sf.zekr.ZekrMain.startZekr(ZekrMain.java:51)
    at net.sf.zekr.ZekrMain.main(ZekrMain.java:94)
```

Please advise me.

Answer (score 11):

This just work for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

The original topic: [Open eclipse juno with error “No more handles …” in Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125044/open-eclipse-juno-with-error-no-more-handles-in-ubuntu-12-04?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Got the same issue, and I can confirm this works on my machine.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and use this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tcsh
```

and run `tcsh` command in the terminal and the two command to set the environmental variable

```
tcsh
setenv MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME /usr/lib/mozilla
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

Now, try to execute the application again. It should be launched without errors.

([Source](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinuxrcp))

Comment: z3r0n@Blue-Box:~$ setenv MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME /usr/lib/mozilla
No command 'setenv' found, did you mean:
 Command 'netenv' from package 'netenv' (universe)
setenv: command not found
z3r0n@Blue-Box:~$ setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}No command 'setenv' found, did you mean:
 Command 'netenv' from package 'netenv' (universe)
setenv: command not found

Comment: I encountered errors after using the command... it is not installed. I dont have eclipse installed could it be another factor

Comment: @AcessDenied You needed to install `tcsh`. I've updated the answer. Check now

Comment: still i get that error... No command 'setenv' found, did you mean:
 Command 'netenv' from package 'netenv' (universe)
setenv: command not found

Comment: @AcessDenied install `tcsh` please with `sudo apt-get install tcsh`

Comment: I did... No command 'setenv' found, did you mean: Command 'netenv' from package 'netenv' (universe) setenv: command not found

Comment: @AcessDenied Please read my answer carefully. You have to run `tcsh` command after installation.

Comment: z3r0n@Blue-Box:~$ tsch
No command 'tsch' found, did you mean:
 Command 'sch' from package 'scheme2c' (universe)
 Command 'tcsh' from package 'tcsh' (universe)
 Command 'xsch' from package 'alliance' (universe)
 Command 'tscd' from package 'tcm' (universe)
tsch: command not found       the error i encounterd

Comment: PLease put your updates in your QUESTION! Not buried in the comments!

Comment: @AcessDenied Let's discuss this on [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6217/discussion-about-zekr-question)

Comment: I couldnt log into the chat room

Answer (score 0):

Selamun aleykum,

Put the following code at the beginning of zekr.sh (located in /usr/bin) 
(if your firefox is installed in /usr/lib/firefox):

`export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/firefox`

Source: http://zekr.org/wiki/Installation#Other_Linux_distributions