# “MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set” zekr quran ubuntu 13.04 ERROR

Tags: firefox, 13.04, java, eclipse, mozilla

I have installed zekr Quran study software in ubuntu 13.04, but it showes error

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]  
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initMozilla(Mozilla.java:1939)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Mozilla.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.(Browser.java:99)
    at net.sf.zekr.ui.QuranForm.makeFrame(QuranForm.java:628)
    at net.sf.zekr.ui.QuranForm.init(QuranForm.java:340)
    at net.sf.zekr.ui.QuranForm.(QuranForm.java:319)
    at net.sf.zekr.ZekrMain.startZekr(ZekrMain.java:51)
    at net.sf.zekr.ZekrMain.main(ZekrMain.java:94)
```

then I executed the following commands

```
tcsh  
setenv MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME /usr/lib/firefox  
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`
```

But it showes error again

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH: Undefined variable.`

Now what should I do? Pls help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you are:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/289325/154840).

Comment: Thx it worked for me...

Comment: If same answer exists for same question in Ask Ubuntu, it is a duplicate. Flag the question in these case

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Zekr portable for Linux](http://zekr.org/download.html) on any distribution.